# catch exception in a fashionable way

Tags: php, exception

I have an extended class for dateTime who makes some extra validation steps.
When a given date is invalid, it throws an exception.
Now I have some MySQL records with dates in zero (0000-00-00 00:00:00). In those cases, I want to show the text "never", so I have to catch the exception, and now I have this horrible mess...

```
    try
    {
        $sellDate = new Date();
        $sellDate ->setFromMySQL($this->_data['lastSell']);
        $sellDateDMY = $dateSell->getDMY(TRUE);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        if($e->getMessage() == 'Invalid date.')
            $sellDateDMY = 'Never';
        else
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
    $info[] = array('desc' => 'Last Sell: '      , 'data' => $sellDateDMY);
```

Any better way to do this?

Comment: You can just `throw $e;`, no need to `new` another `Exception($e -> getMessage())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on which method it is that throws. The simplest would be to subclass `Date` again (maybe as `NullableDate`?) and override that method to not throw. The `getDMY` method would then return `null`, at which point you can display `Never` using the ternary operator `?:`.

This way you won't have to use the ugly `try`/`catch`, and the intent of the code will also be clear to anyone who reads it for info on validation requirements -- by instantiating a `NullableDate` you definitely don't mind if its value is empty.

Comment: Seems like a sensible solution, But I'm starting to think I'm shooting myself in the foot... :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
class DateException extends Exception {
  public function __construct(Exception $e) {
     if($e->getMessage() == 'Invalid date.') {
        $this->message = 'Never';
     } else {
         $this->message = $e->getMessage();
     }
  }
}
```

---

```
try
{
    $sellDate = new Date();
    $sellDate ->setFromMySQL($this->_data['lastSell']);
    $sellDateDMY = $dateSell->getDMY(TRUE);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    throw new DateException($e);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start throwing different type of exceptions. Specific to the problem. Instead of the generic catch, you could do this

```
catch (DateInvalidException $de) {
  //code
} catch (DateSomeOtherException $dso) {
 //code
} catch (Exception $e) {
  //general
}
```

**But that's not a good solution. You're mixing up program exceptions and error validations.**

Answer (score 0):

Make your own Exception class for your Date functions.

```
class MyOwnDateException extends Exception {
    ... // Do something or probably nothing
}
```

And call it in your code:

```
try {
    if($someErrorYouWantToCatch) {
        throw new MyOwnDateException("error message", 100 /* Error code = optional */);
    }
} catch(MyOwnDateException $mode) {
    $sellDateDMY = 'Never';
}
```